# Is there an efficient way to replace text matching the entire content of one file with the entire content of another file?

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed

I have three files

```
~/naive-file.txt
~/old-text.txt
~/new-text.txt
```

I want to find every instance where the contents of `~/old-text.txt` occurs in `~/naive-file.txt` and replace those occurrences with the contents of `~/new-text.txt`. I'm sure this is doable with `sed` or `awk` but I can't seem to figure out the right command. Is this possible?

For instance, suppose the content of `~/naive-file.txt` is

```
$ cat ~/naive-file.txt
Sed id ligula quis est convallis tempor.

This is the old text.

It might have multiple lines and some special characters like these \ { & % #)!
etc...


Nunc aliquet, augue nec adipiscing interdum, lacus tellus malesuada massa, quis
varius mi purus non odio.
```

Suppose the content of `~/old-text.txt` is

```
$ cat ~/old-text.txt
This is the old text.

It might have multiple lines and some special characters like these \ { & % #)!
etc...
```

Suppose the content of `~/new-text.txt` is

```
$ cat ~/new-text.txt
This is the new text.

It could also have multiple lines and special characters like these \ { & %
etc...
```

Running my desired command would then produce

```
Sed id ligula quis est convallis tempor.

This is the new text.

It could also have multiple lines and special characters like these \ { & %
etc...


Nunc aliquet, augue nec adipiscing interdum, lacus tellus malesuada massa, quis
varius mi purus non odio.
```

Comment: first string from `old-text.txt` to be replaced with first string from `new-text.txt` and so on?

Comment: @iruvar I'll add an example to clarify.

Comment: @iruvar Example added.

Comment: Are the number of lines the same in old and new files?

Comment: No. I probably should have made that clear in my example.

Answer (score 5):

Perl to the rescue!

Read the replacements pairs into a hash. Then read the input line by line and try to replace the matches.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

open my $ot, '<', 'old-text.txt' or die $!;
chomp( my @lines = <$ot> );
open my $nt, '<', 'new-text.txt' or die $!;
my %replace;
@replace{@lines} = <$nt>;
chomp for values %replace;

my $regex = join '|', map quotemeta, @lines;
open my $in, 'naive-file.txt' or die $!;
while (<$in>) {
    s/($regex)/$replace{$1}/;
    print;
}
```

If some of the strings to be replaced are substrings of other strings to be replaced, you need to sort the strings in the regular expression by their length descending, i.e.

```
my $regex = join '|', map quotemeta, sort { length $b <=> length $a } @lines;
```

Comment: what is the purpose of `$regex`, coz it's not being used here?

Comment: Good point, fixed.

Comment: Isn’t this line-by-line while the OP wanted to replace one big bunch of bytes with another big bunch?

Comment: So how should one match the blocks to replace? Are they separated by two newline?

Answer (score 4):

**Bash**

Replace first match:

```
target=$(cat naive-file.txt)
old=$(cat old-text.txt)
new=$(cat new-text.txt)
echo "${target/"$old"/"$new"}"
```

Replace all match:

```
echo "${target//"$old"/"$new"}"
```

Replace beginning match:

```
echo "${target/#"$old"/"$new"}"
```

Replace end match:

```
echo "${target/%"$old"/"$new"}"
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is the GNU `awk` one-liner:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{old[++k]=$0}FILENAME=="new-text.txt"{new[FNR]=$0}
     FILENAME=="naive-file.txt"{for(i=1;i<k;i++)if(old[i]==$0)$0=new[i];print}'\
     old-text.txt new-text.txt naive-file.txt
```

Might not be suitable for very large files as all patterns are first stored into arrays.

Output:

```
Sed id ligula quis est convallis tempor.

This is the new text.

It could also have multiple lines and special characters like these \ { & %
etc...


Nunc aliquet, augue nec adipiscing interdum, lacus tellus malesuada massa, quis
varius mi purus non odio.
```

Comment: for efficiency reasons you want to be breaking out of the loop after a match is found? Of course that also changes the behaviour of the program if the contents of old and new files are such that a replacement string could itself subsequently qualify for replacement

Comment: @iruvar I assumed from OP question that the patterns are unique and form whole lines. One can break the loop or even (instead of the loop) take and remove the first element from the array if patterns appear in the same order - that should be much faster for large files.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ perl -0777ne '
     $A[@ARGV] = $_;
     @ARGV and next;
     my($naive, $new, $old) = @A;
     while ( index($naive,$old,$p) > -1 ) {
        substr($naive, index($naive,$old,$p), length($old)) = $new;
        $p = index($naive,$old,length($old)) ;
      }
      print $naive;
' old.txt new.txt naive.txt
```